# Problems with flashing ESP Wroom-02

Tags: nodemcu, firmware, esp32, flashing

So I am having issues with flashing an ESP Wroom-02 Wifi chip. The one that I have gotten is the kind with built-in micro USB port so I can just connect a cable from my laptop straight to the WiFi chip and program it. On the board there is also two button labelled Flash and Reset.

I have looked through Espressif's official documents and online guides as well. All I want is to test the various AT commands.

```
Here are some of the files that I have from the official Espressif website under the folder /ESP8266_AT_Bin_V1.7/bin:
blank.bin -> 4KB
boot_v1.2.bin -> 2KB
boot_v1.6.bin -> 4KB
boot_v1.7.bin -> 4KB
esp_init_data_default_v0.5.bin -> 1KB
esp_init_data_default_v0.8.bin -> 1KB

/ESP8266_AT_Bin_V1.7/bin/at/1024+1024
user1.2048.new.bin -> 445KB
user2.2048.new.bin -> 445KB
```

I am using the ESP Flash Download Tool from Espressif themselves.
Settings such as:

```
CrystalFreq: 26M
SPI Speed: 40MHZ
SPI Mode: QIO / DIO (tried both)
Flash Size: 4Mbit 2Mbit 8Mbit 16Mbit 32Mbit 16Mbit-C1 32Mbit-C1


DETECTED INFO:
flash devID -> 4015h QUAD; 16Mbit
crystal -> 26Mhz
```

So after trying various combinations of the files and settings (while following the official manual and online guides), there were times I see the the sentence "-> ready" from the serial monitor but when I send the command AT or AT+GMR I get backed "-> ERROR".

What could be the issue? I would really appreciate some help with this. If anyone of you managed to successfully flashed the Wroom-02 with the provided firmware from Espressif and get the correct reply when sending commands such as AT or AT+GMR, please share the settings that you used when flashing the firmware (e.g. the memory address for the various files and Spi Flash Config).

Much thanks in advance!

This is what I get when I connect it using a serial terminal and hit the reset button.

[ESP8266 Bootloader Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imCIR.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow ok. Apparently what I did was correct. Here is the setting that I used:

[ESP Wroom-02 Flash Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUAmb.jpg)

Your result may vary depending on the size of flash that your Wroom-02 comes with. On some tutorials you might notice a difference in the FLASH SIZE option. Don't ask me why but mine just works with 16Mbit-C1. Part of the DETECTED INFO returned to me also showed 16Mbit anyway.

So after flashing and then connecting it to a serial monitor with baud rate 74880 on Arduino IDE and then pressing a reset would give me results like what I have posted in my question previously. That actually is correct. Here comes the reason why I thought it wasn't working.

Carriage Return.

[Only Newline option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mIch.jpg)

I sent the commands with only the Newline enabled. Therefore it kept returning ERROR.

This is what should have been done.

[Newline & Carriage Return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Msj.jpg)

Now when you send the commands with NL & CR enabled, both AT and AT+GMR commands work now.

This is from Espressif's documentation under the AT Instruction Set pdf.

[Flash Map from Espressif's AT Instruction Set pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Hyd.jpg)

You might have noticed that my initial flash settings uses only 4 files while the official flash map uses 6 files. I can ascertain that both ways can successfully flash the firmware onto the chip. AT and AT+GMR command work as well.